# this product didn't install successfully: unable to connect to remote server

Tags: python, iis, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to install `python` and `WFastCGI` using `IIS web platform installer` it fails and give me this error :

[image]

Here is the log :

[Link for full log text](https://textuploader.com/1dl2b)

Comment: It might be a temp issue, but you should keep in mind that Microsoft no longer wants you to run Python on IIS https://blog.lextudio.com/shifting-to-azure-app-service-on-linux-b216f4584b03 Things like WFastCGI are obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't install the python with fastcgi directly through the platform.

I suggest you could install it by downloading the python installer and using the powershell commnd.

More details, you could refer to below command:

1. Download and install the python.exe from this [url](https://www.python.org/about/).
2. Run below command with the powershell.

   pip install wfastcgi

[image]

More details about how to run python applicaiton on the IIS, you could refer to below article:

https://gist.github.com/dvas0004/3d26c25d614c54ecdf296003d68cddaa